# Swift 3: Authenticate with custom token(s), managing requests with server (node.js)

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is not much information in the Firebase Docs on dealing with custom tokens.

I have set up a server with `node.js`, but I don't know how to manage requests to the server to send the information back to the app and vice-versa. Any resources on how to achieve this?

This is the code for the `node.js` server

```
var serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
var firebase = require('firebase');
var path = require("path");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var refreshToken;

var uid = 'clientId';
var additionalClaims = {
  admin: true, manager: true, menuAccess: true
};
var clientIdToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims);

console.log(clientIdToken)

firebase.initializeApp({

    serviceAccount: path.resolve(__dirname, '/Users/myUserName/Desktop/nodeClient/service-account.json'),
    databaseURL: "https://<firebase-project>.firebaseio.com/",
    databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
      uid: "clientId"
    }

});
```

In xcode:

```
    func login (email: String, password: String, onComplete: Completion?) {
        self.showActivityIndicatory(uiView: self.uiView)
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {

                self.handleFirebaseError(error: error! as NSError, onComplete: onComplete)

                self.stopAnimating()

            } else {

                // User successfully logged in

                FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
                    if user != nil {

                        let userUpdate = ["provider": String(describing:FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.providerID), "email": "email": String(describing: FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email!) ]
                        DataService.instance.registerUsers(uid: (user?.uid)!, user: userUpdate)

                        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken: "clientIdToken") {(user, error) in

                            if user != nil {
                                print("Got here somehow..")
                                print(user?.uid)

// as I create a custom token, this user?.uid should be "clientId", right?

                            } else {
                                print(error)

// I get an error here
                            }

                        }

                        print("Signed in")

                    } else {
                        print("NOT SIGNED IN")
                    }
                }

                let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeSegue", sender: nil)

                }

                }

            })

    }
```

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17000 "The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation., error_name=ERROR_INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN})

How shall I proceed? I know I have to send the credentials to my server from the app, but how do I achieve this? I am thinking of digging into `JWT` and `Alamofire`, and I have searched for days to solve this particular problem. I have encountered other programmers tackling the same issue.

Comment: I have figured out a way to use security rules to enable users to access specific sections of the database of the app. I just need to figure out this custom token issue to enable login with username.

Comment: Make sure you are using the same project for the client side code and the admin node.js sdk code.

Comment: I have the same URL project for the admin and firebase.initializeApp. But the admin seems to give me an error whenever I try to initialize it

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. What error is the admin sdk giving you when you initialize it?